# Obtengo mas datos en LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Tengo una consulta a un server link, la cual me traigo informacion de dos tablas

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(LINKED-S,'
    SELECT
    T1.CODIGO_CLIENTE,
    T1.CODIGO_DEUDOR,
    T1.RUT_DEUDOR,
    T2.RAZON_SOCIAL,
    T2.DIRECCION
    FROM FACTURAS T1
    LEFT COMPANIAS T2
       ON T1.RUT = T2.RUT
')
```

Esa consulta me arroja 44479 registros.
El asunto es que me pidieron complementar informacion, la cual se obtiene desde una tabla local, por lo cual modifique la consulta a esta:

```
SELECT TA.*, TB.MATRIZ, TB.CONTACTO
FROM OPENQUERY(LINKED-S,'
   SELECT
      T1.CODIGO_CLIENTE,
      T1.CODIGO_DEUDOR,
      T1.RUT_DEUDOR,
      T2.RAZON_SOCIAL,
      T2.DIRECCION
      FROM FACTURAS T1
      LEFT COMPANIAS T2
         ON T1.RUT = T2.RUT
    ') AS TA
LEFT JOIN CONTACTOS AS TB
   ON TA.RUT_DEUDOR = TB.Rut
```

El asunto de esta query, es que ontengo mas registros que la anterior query (44732), por lo que pense puede ser que haya datos duplicados, asi que inclui la sentencia `DISTINCT` en el primer select, pero solo disminuyo un par de registros menos.

La idea es obtener la misma cantidad de registros que de la query original, pero agregando los otros dos campos adicionales que piden de la otra tabla.

Comment: Seguramente es porque Rut no es una llave única en la tabla de Contactos.

Comment: Debe haber dos compañias con el mismo RUT

Answer (score 0):

Logre resolver en cierto punto lo que necesitaba.
La empresa ahora copia esas tablas a local, asi que opte por manejar de la siguiente forma el caso:

```
SELECT
   T1.CODIGO_CLIENTE,
   T1.CODIGO_DEUDOR,
   T1.RUT_DEUDOR,
   T2.RAZON_SOCIAL,
   T2.DIRECCION
   (
      SELECT TOP 1 MATRIZ
      FROM CONTACTOS
      WHERE Rut = RUT_DEUDOR
   ) AS MATRIZ,
   (
      SELECT TOP 1 CONTACTO
      FROM CONTACTOS
      WHERE Rut = RUT_DEUDOR
   ) AS CONTACTO
FROM FACTURAS
```

Se que no es la mejor forma y la mas elegante, pero sirve al proposito. Si alguien tiene una forma mejor de manejarlo, se los agradeceria.